Summing dictionary values in C#
I'm trying to sum some values over a year. My code runs per day, so I need to sum these values after the calculations. The goal is then to export them back to SQL. I've already set up a table and I did manage to export some values to the table, but only the daily values and not the yearly yet.
// YEAR OVERVIEW
OptResultDataYear optResultDataYear = new OptResultDataYear();

// Variations in price
List<float> varprijs = new List<float> { 0.06f, 0.08f, 0.10f, 0.12f, 0.14f, 0.16f, 0.18f };

// Create dictionaries for storing the values
Dictionary<float, OptResultYear> yearlyResults = varPrijs.ToDictionary(co => co, co => new OptResultYear { AfdelingId = afd.AfdelingsId, variatiePrijs = co });

// SQL output
OptResultYear optResultYear= new OptResultYear();

for (DateTime date = startYear; date < endYear; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    foreach (float co in varprijs)
    {
        // Calculate the optimal results with the varPrijs
        ResultScenDay optResultvar = await DayCalc.RunOcapOptimaalDayAsync(afd.AfdelingsId, date, 3600, (int)ScenarioType.Optimal, co, null); // per dag met uurdata.

       // Analyze the code
       optResultYear = analysePeriode.FillOptResultYear(afd.AfdelingsId, kenm.TeeltOppHa, date, optResultvar, co, null);

      // Collect the required values
      yearlyResults[co].OptTotalDos += (float)optResultYear.OptTotalDos;
      yearlyResults[co].OptDos1 += (float)optResultYear.OptDos1;
      yearlyResults[co].OptDos2 += (float)optResultYear.OptDos2;
      yearlyResults[co].OptCost += (float)optResultYear.OptCost;
      yearlyResults[co].OptProductie += (float)optResultYear.OptProductie;
      yearlyResultsCO2[co].OptConcLp += (float)optResultYear.OptConcLp;

      // Set the date for the last entry
      yearlyResultsCO2[co].Datum = date;
   }
}

The values on the right (the optResultYear.) do have values, and they are calculated as required. However, When adding them to my dictionary I only get NULL values.
Does anyone know how to resolve this or know a better option?

Why are you using "+="?  A null plus a value is a null.

var yr = yearlyResults[co]; yr.OptTotalDos = (yr.OptTotalDos ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptTotalDos;  yr.OptDos1 = (yr.OptDos1 ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptDos1; .... But may this can de done in SQL with a GROUP BY YEAR(date) and SUM(xy) aggregates.

@jdweng I'm still quite new at c#, so I did not know that dictionaries automatically have a null values.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you for this, I need this to be done in C# instead of SQL, but the ??0f works as needed. Thank you guys for your help.

Obligatory warning about using floating point types for monetary amounts. Sums might not result in what you expect them to be.

Also, float is a terrible type to use as a dictionary key - two float values that should be identical can have different actual values and hash codes. Since you're using a fixed set of constant values you're probably not seeing that but integer would be better (sacling them up by 100).

Note that the default value for a nullable type is null and null propagates. I.e., null + x == null.
You can use the null-coalescing operator ?? to convert a null value to a desired value.
I.e., (null ?? n) + x == n + x
var yr = yearlyResults[co];
yr.OptTotalDos = (yr.OptTotalDos ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptTotalDos;
yr.OptDos1 = (yr.OptDos1 ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptDos1;
yr.OptDos2 = (yr.OptDos2 ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptDos2;
yr.OptCost = (yr.OptCost ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptCost;
yr.OptProductie = (yr.OptProductie ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptProductie;

var yrCOo2 = yearlyResultsCO2[co];
yrCOo2.OptConcLp = (yrCOo2.OptConcLp ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptConcLp;
yrCOo2.Datum = date;

I assume that the dictionary entries are of a class type (i.e., a reference type). Then you can access the dictionary only once by assigning the entries to a temporary variable: var yr = yearlyResults[co];.
You must be careful with structs, since the dictionary will return you a copy of it instead of a reference. If it was a struct you would have to insert it to the dictionary again at the end: yearlyResults[co] = yr;

The solution was that adding a NULL value with an actual value turns into a NULL value. Therefore,
var yr = yearlyResults[co];

yr.OptTotalDos = (yr.OptTotalDos ?? 0f) + (float)optResultYear.OptTotalDos;  

Adding the yr.OptTotalDos ?? 0f ensured that if the value is NULL then the value would be changed to 0, causing it to continue calculating.
